# How do I configure clang in GPS

Tags: gnat, gnat-gps

GPS (Gnat Programming Studio) uses clang to do live diagnostics. Unfortunately I can't find any documentation on how to configure it. I'd like to tell it to use C++11 so it doesn't complain about nullptr not being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Though you asked it about year ago......

Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> C & C++ -> Show live clang diagnostics

Comment: It's a start but not what I need. That allows for turning it on/off but doesn't let you configure clang to treat C++11 syntax as valid. (At least not in the GPS version I'm running: 17.1).